# Issue in Implement Magento ver. 2.2.2 on subdomain

Tags: php, redirect, subdomain, magento2

i need some help regarding magneto v2.2.2..
want to implement whole magneto in new folder ABCDFOLDER in public_html/

- i just copied all my website files and folder in to new folder called ABCDFOLDER
- i have already created a subdomain and point to this ABCDFOLDER
- and already created new database and imported previous database into
  it..!!
- already edit core_data table secure and unsecure with subdomain link
- ABCDFOLDER/app/etc/env.php edited with new database info which i was created..

Issue is when ever open subdomain url in browser they redirect me to main site ... can't find any solution on other site please help me in this :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remove the cache folders already?

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache
```

[See also](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134245/base-url-change-magento2-1)

Comment: Yes or you just login via ftp and remove the named directories via ftp-client. But SSH is way much faster. Please do not delete the full var directory. Just the named ones.